# MS-Word Macro - replace - confirming after work

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, confirmation

I am not an engineer, and I am not IT worker. But I am... a sport journalist.

I write many articles on the road. I use for this Google Voice. But we have one problem with polish language in Google Voice. It doesn't... convert punctuation marks.

I created The Macro in Microsoft Word. But it is not 100% to my satisfaction. I have problem with confirming changes after all of work.

After use my Macro, I need to push the button 'YES' after its work. MS-Word ask me: "MS-Word finished searching of selected text. Numbers of changes: 0/1/2 etc. Should I search the rest of the document?".

I have 11 replacements in Macro and every word I need push YES... 11 times (even when it replaces 0 times) :)

I attached my Macro, maybe someone from your community could help and modify my idea. Thanks a lot, best regards.

```
Sub GoogleVoice()
'
' GoogleVoice Makro
'
'
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " przecinek"
        .Replacement.Text = ","
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " kropka"
        .Replacement.Text = "."
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " dwukropek"
        .Replacement.Text = ":"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "myślnik"
        .Replacement.Text = "-"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " znak zapytania"
        .Replacement.Text = "?"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " wykrzyknik"
        .Replacement.Text = "!"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " cudzysłów"
        .Replacement.Text = """"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " zamknij nawias"
        .Replacement.Text = ")"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
      Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "trzykropek"
        .Replacement.Text = "..."
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " nawias "
        .Replacement.Text = "("
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " enter"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompts are caused by wdFindAsk. Your code can also be greatly simplified. Try:

```
Sub GoogleVoice()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Format = False
  .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = False
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .MatchSoundsLike = False
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
  .Text = " przecinek"
  .Replacement.Text = ","
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = " kropka"
  .Replacement.Text = "."
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = " dwukropek"
  .Replacement.Text = ":"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "myslnik"
  .Replacement.Text = "-"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = " znak zapytania"
  .Replacement.Text = "?"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = " wykrzyknik"
  .Replacement.Text = "!"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = " cudzysłów"
  .Replacement.Text = """"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = " zamknij nawias"
  .Replacement.Text = ")"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "trzykropek"
  .Replacement.Text = "..."
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = " nawias "
  .Replacement.Text = "("
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = " enter"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```